# JS NPM package into Apache Archiva

Tags: npm, archiva

I have a npm package and want to store it to archiva as per versions, same as NPM repository. Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Do you know if this is possible? Does Archiva support npm packages?

Comment: No, I'm using Verdaccio (https://verdaccio.org/)